# Store and loading large plists

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, plist

I am parsing some xml and storing the result in a plist save it to file. I later frequently use that plist to search, add/remove stuff and then save it back.

Now, I don't have any problem with this, everything works fine, im just wondering if there's a better/more efficient/faster way of doing this?

About the plist: array of 200 dictionaries with 150 entries each. Some of those entries are array themselves with sub dictionaries of 50-100 entries... (you get the point)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running into performance problems I would suggest not worrying about it and just focus on getting the rest of app completed. Premature optimization is the root of all evil (someone had to say it right?).

If you decide that the time has come to make that part of your app as efficient as possible then we would need to see that actual code that you are using to determine if there are more efficient ways to do it. Considering your description of the plist I would guess that if there was anything incredibly inefficient with your strategy and/or implementation then you would already be running up against it with respect to performance.

Comment: i agree, don't optimize until you need to.  CoreData may be an option if you are accessing/removing/updating random small parts of the data

Comment: Thanks..i guess i'll stick with what I have as I don't have any problems. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" :)